# Error installing json in Ruby on Rails [ Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I typed create new rails app with command: `rails new app`

it can not install json extension

this message is displayed:

```
Installing json (1.8.0)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [generator.o] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-
1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ex
t/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

what is the solution for this problem????

Comment: What is in the file `C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out`? That should indicate why the compilation failed.

Comment: @claptimes I installed Dev Kit, and its same problem!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `make` is trying to use a command named `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` to compile the file `generator.c`. Is this in `cygwin`? I think you just need to install `gcc` using the cygwin installer.

Comment: @iLHilalista I assume by your comment in your question that installing Dev Kit did not work. I also assume that you made sure to install gcc with the cygwin package installer if you are using cygwin. The only next step I can think of is to look up the file `gem_make.out` and see if you can find anything that gives further clues to why `make` is unable to find `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`.

Comment: i cannot install gcc ..